# GET request endpoint results rider_id is null

Tags: uber-api

why is it that the riders have a null rider_id in the example? but the description says otherwise? `riders[].rider_id` : The hashed rider uuid. It doesnt say anything about it being may be null. Else what's the point of returning it. [GET request](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get)

or is just an example, and the actual response has all of these ids not null

```
{
  "product_id": "17cb78a7-b672-4d34-a288-a6c6e44d5315",
  "request_id": "a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d",
  "status": "accepted",
  "surge_multiplier": 1.0,
  "shared": true,
  "driver": {
    "phone_number": "(555)555-5555",
    "sms_number": "(555)555-5555",
    "rating": 5,
    "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/img.jpeg",
    "name": "Bob"
  },
  "vehicle": {
    "make": "Bugatti",
    "model": "Veyron",
    "license_plate": "I<3Uber",
    "picture_url": "https:\/\/d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net\/car.jpeg"
  },
  "location": {
    "latitude": 37.3382129093,
    "longitude": -121.8863287568,
    "bearing": 328
  },
  "pickup": {
    "latitude": 37.3303463,
    "longitude": -121.8890484,
    "eta": 5
  },
  "destination": {
    "latitude": 37.6213129,
    "longitude": -122.3789554,
    "eta": 19
  },
  "waypoints": [
    {
       "rider_id":null,
       "latitude":37.77508531,
       "type":"pickup",
       "longitude":-122.3976683872
    },
    {
       "rider_id":null,
       "latitude":37.773133,
       "type":"dropoff",
       "longitude":-122.415069
    },
    {
       "rider_id":"8KwsIO_YG6Y2jijSMf",
       "latitude":37.7752423,
       "type":"dropoff",
       "longitude":-122.4175658
    }
  ],
  "riders": [
    {
       "rider_id":"8KwsIO_YG6Y2jijSMf",
       "first_name":"Alec",
       "me": true
    },
    {
       "rider_id":null,
       "first_name":"Kevin",
       "me": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `riders` array, as specified in the [GET /request/{request_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get) reference page, is returned only for shared rides (uberPOOL rides). You will only be able to get a non-null `rider_id` if that rider account has already authenticated with your developer app.

This means that if any `rider_id` in the `riders` array is `null`, the rider account associated with that `rider_id` has not authenticated with your app.